Cannot load ttf font file with reportlab, throws OSError
I want to load a custom font in my PdfCreator class which uses reportlab to create these Pdfs. When I initialize the class, I define the font path and name, but when executing I only get a lot of errors thrown.
Here is the whole traceback:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 523, in open_for_read
    return open_for_read_by_name(name,mode)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 463, in open_for_read_by_name
    return open(name,mode)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../fonts/source-sans-pro.regular.ttf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 530, in open_for_read
    return BytesIO((datareader if name[:5].lower()=='data:' else rlUrlRead)(name))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 476, in rlUrlRead
    return urlopen(name).read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 215, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 499, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 318, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 344, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 373, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: '../../fonts/source-sans-pro.regular.ttf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 151, in TTFOpenFile
    f = open_for_read(fn,'rb')
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 534, in open_for_read
    return open_for_read(name,mode)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 532, in open_for_read
    raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name)
OSError: Cannot open resource "../../fonts/source-sans-pro.regular.ttf"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1967, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\app\ui\pages\student_page.py", line 90, in <lambda>
    self.name_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event: self.create_cover_pdf())
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\app\ui\pages\student_page.py", line 23, in create_cover_pdf
    PdfCreatorCover(
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\app\utils\pdf_creator.py", line 188, in __init__
    super().__init__(name, eval_type, year, school_year, birthday, missing_days, excused_days, attending_year, filepath, preview)
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\app\utils\pdf_creator.py", line 45, in __init__
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont(self.font_name_regular, self.font_path_regular))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 1192, in __init__
    self.face = TTFontFace(filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 1073, in __init__
    TTFontFile.__init__(self, filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 439, in __init__
    TTFontParser.__init__(self, file, validate=validate,subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 175, in __init__
    self.readFile(file)
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 251, in readFile
    self.filename, f = TTFOpenFile(f)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Earth\PycharmProjects\Peeneburg0.2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py", line 161, in TTFOpenFile
    raise TTFError('Can\'t open file "%s"' % fn)
reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts.TTFError: Can't open file "../../fonts/source-sans-pro.regular.ttf"

The files are definitely there and I tried this code (only changed the the path) in my proof of concept and it worked flawless. I tried if my project structure was the problem and tried different positions for my fonts folder, but nothing did work. But it did refactor the variable in the PdfCreator class.
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.lib.colors import black, gray, white
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth


class PdfCreator:
    def __init__(# something):
        // initializing variables

        self.font_name_regular = 'Source Sans Pro'
        self.font_path_regular = '../../fonts/source-sans-pro.regular.ttf'
        self.font_name_bold = 'Source Sans Pro Bold'
        self.font_path_bold = '../../fonts/source-sans-pro.bold.ttf'

        self.pagesize = A4
        self.canvas = canvas.Canvas(self.pdf_path, pagesize=self.pagesize)
        self.width, self.height = self.pagesize

        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont(self.font_name_regular, self.font_path_regular))
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont(self.font_name_bold, self.font_path_bold))

// some irrelevant more code



@KJ so I moved it to the same directory as PdfCreator (and it refactored the variables font_path_x automatically) and it still doesn't work. What would be the next step?
